# Can I cancel my edit pending for review?

Tags: support

I don't have enough reputation on any SE site to bypass the peer review phase for edits. Is there a way to undo or delete my edit suggestion?

Comment: No, there is no way to cancel your suggested edit. You'll just have to wait and hope that the reviewers reject it. If you want to _fix_ your suggestion instead, you can do that. Edit the same post, and the edits will, so long as it has not gone through yet, merge into your original suggested edit.